# Simple C++ loop takes up entire RAM

Tags: c++

I was doing some coding on C++ just to get used to its syntax (I'm Java developer). However, I've written the code below and it takes up the entire RAM in seconds, the more free RAM you have, the faster program takes it up. When I uncomment the `cout` method to print current string at the end of every loop, it starts to take RAM up drastically slower (10-15mb in a minute). Does printing operation slows the cycle that much, or is there another reason?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string inf;
    list<string> myList;

    for(;;){
        inf += "___ ";
        myList.push_back(inf);
        //cout << inf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop uses more and more memory, so observed behavior seems logical. Printing is "slow"...

Comment: what do you mean with "returns back to normal, fills slowly" ?

Comment: oh, you mean when you are printing something on the screen then the program runs slower, ie it takes more time before it blows up? Printing something on the screen is extremely slow comared to most stuff you can do on the cpu

Comment: I couldn't catch the logic behind your reasoning.

Comment: *I couldn't catch the logic behind this behaviour.*  Appending is (say) 1 unit of work.  Output is (say) 10,000 units of work.  In this hypothetical case, output after every append will slow things down by a factor of x10000.

Comment: *I'm just appending simple symbol into the list* - no, you append copies of a growing string into the list. `push_back()` makes a copy, see https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah, I think about this, but couldn't figure out that printing can make that huge difference in operation time, I'm not experienced enough. Thank you.

Comment: @tevemadar  thank you. I searched for c++ list declaration in Internet to look for syntax, and I see this method first to append something into list, so I rushed to try it without deeping into details what it actually does. Thanks for clarification, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is simply fact that i/o operations are really slow compared to appending list. Therefore this seemed to be work "okay". This loop is just infinite, never stops.

Answer (score 4):

for(;;) is an infenite loop.

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
  // code block to be executed
}
```

**Statement 1** is executed (one time) before the execution of the code block.

**Statement 2** defines the condition for executing the code block.

**Statement 3** is executed (every time) after the code block has been executed.

Since your statement 2 is empty it defaults to true, so this loop keeps on running.

Comment: You've misread the question: `Does printing operation slows the cycle that much, or is there another reason?` - OP is asking why using `cout` causes a difference in speed.

Answer (score 2):

you `for(;;)` loop is infinite and as such `mylist` is continually expanded until it has filled your entire RAM. The execution time of appending simple symbol into the list is extremely low, so your RAM is filled extremely fast. When `cout` is added to the loop, the loop has to output before it can append more to `mylist`. The execution time of outputting takes significantly longer than appending and as such the time between loops is slowed. This in turn means your RAM will be filled more slowly.